# Javascript Dynamically replace div content on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a HTML5 app and i need to dynamically change the content of a div with different html files depending on the menu select. The code I currently have loads the menu however when I click on a button I receive a short message "Error loading page" that disappears after a few seconds. I've fiddled around with it myself and can't quite figure out what is going wrong so I'll show the code I currently have.

index.html -

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="index">
<div id="wrapper">
    <div data-role="controlgroup" data-corners="false" data-position="left">
        <a href="/html/home.html" id="home" data-role="button">HOME</a>
        <a href="/html/tracking.html" id="track" data-role="button">TRACKING</a>
        <a href="/html/favourites.html" id="fav" data-role="button">FAVOURITES</a>
        <a href="/html/setting.html" id="set" data-role="button">SETTINGS</a>
        <a href="/html/login.html" id="login" data-role="button">LOG IN</a>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="header" data-role="header" data-theme="b">
            <a id="bars-button" data-icon="bars" class="ui-btn-right" style="margin-top:0px;" href="#navpanel">MENU</a>

        </div>
        <div id="dMain"> </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>  

<script> 
//$(document).ready(function(){
//$('#home').click(function(){  
//    $('#dMain').load('/html/home.html');
// });
//});

</script>    
</body>
```

home.html -

```
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="home">
<h1>Hello</h1>
<h2>This is the home page</h2>
<p>it will contain about us information</p> 
</div>
</body>
```

I have changed bits and pieces so it is not in a working state currently but any suggestions on how to fix/improve this code would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error I had lay in my home.html file. An incorrect statement in a div that was affecting the ability to display it.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you have jquery library loaded properly which supports ajax if not
load [jquery 1.11](https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js) and [jquery ui 1.10.3](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js) and [theme](https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css)
Try,

```
<script> 
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#home').click(function(e){  
    $('#dMain').load('/html/home.html');
    e.preventDefault();
 });
});

</script>
```

Comment: This method highlights the active button which leads me to believe that the code is working however I am still unable to view the content from home.html in the dMain div in the index.html, the "error loading page" no longer appears, could it be something to do with my home.html page?

Comment: if all files are in /html/ directory then try loading by file name itself. e.g. home.html only. I believe error loading page means your page is not available on that location.

Comment: okay, I've restarted my IDE and it appears to still be receiving "Error Loading Page" even with the changes to file name

Comment: Did you corrected your code? instead of "/html/home.html" try "home.html" only

Comment: Yes I did, and it still doesn't appear to be working. I am still working on it just now.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(function() {

  $('#home').click(function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/html/home.html',
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(response) {
        $('#dMain').html(response);
      }
    });

  });

});
```

Comment: This method works similarly to the answer by Suketu, but I am still unable to see the home.html content in the dMain div, would it be an error with my home.html?

Comment: @TriangleBanana that depends on the content of `home.html`. If `home.html` is in the `html` folder in your root folder than it must work. Of course you must include jQuery library in the head section for this to work.

Comment: Would I need to include the JQuery library in the home.html as well? I have the library included in the index.html and have tried altering "/html/home.html" to just "home.html"

Comment: @TriangleBanana No, if you have jQuery library included in the `<head>` section of your `index.html` document there's no need to include it in `home.html`.